# Python Jupyter/Notebook: How to display a variable as text on a cell without copy/paste

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

It happens to me that when reading/reviewing the code, I becomes easier if I can see the 'look' of the variable a function is processing.

For that, I'd like to display a 'static' version of an instance of that variable (as a visual aid).

That variable may not be there on another run of the notebook, that's why it has to be text, not output.

This is also useful when creating documentation within the notebook.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With this little function

````
#----------------------------------
def vdisplay(var):
    """Converts the var to a pretty string and inserts
    it on a new cell just below the present one.
    
    Then you have to change that 'next cell' type to Markdown and execute it.
    """
    # To print the var nicely.
    from pprint import pformat as pf

    string_to_insert=f"""
This is how it looks like:

```
{pf(var)}
```
"""
    # Create a code cell and insert a string in it
    get_ipython().set_next_input(string_to_insert)
    
    return
#----------------------------------
````

You can do this

```
# This is the data we want to show
x={i:str(i)*i for i in range(10)}
# Show it!
vdisplay(x)
```

Visually:

[image]

I use the mouse intentionally so you can see the steps. Using keyboard shortcuts is much quicker.

> Story: I explored several venues. The last one was a combination of
> `%store var f.txt` and `%load f.txt` but that involved some manual
> work. The evolution of that method is the one above.